# How to upload a .csv file that contains line breaks to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, migration

We are writing some php to move data from a Microsoft SQL database to a MySQL database. The Microsoft data contains user input text, with line breaks and all sorts of wacky stuff

The process we've been working with is as follows:

1. select from a Microsoft SQL database into php array (works fine)
2. processes this into a .csv by looping the fputcsv() function:

   `fputcsv($delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape_char = "\\");`

   (the .csv file looks good when I open it with google sheets)
3. upload the .csv file to the MySQL server with the following code:

   ````
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'c:/filename.csv'
   INTO TABLE tablename
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
   ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   IGNORE 1 ROWS;  ```
   ````

The problem is that when step 3 is executed, the resulting MySQL table is all jumbled up because it appears to get confused with the line breaks in the data, thinking it's a new line in the table.

I noticed the MySQL LOAD DATA command doesn't take the escape character as an argument, but I can't seem to find a way to give it to it. Is this the issue? How can we make this work?

Comment: first of all, have you check the EOL of you csv file? Is it in '\n' or in '\r\n'?

Comment: On Windows server `\r\n` is needed to terminate for Linux `\n` works fine. BTW how you are executing the `load file..` if you are enclosing inside a `concat` you need to escape `\n` with `\\n`

Comment: @ooi18 I'm not sure how to check the EOL, as fputcsv() doesn't take it as an argument, and when I open it with any text editor it shows new lines as actual new lines. How do you recommend we do this?

To answer your second question, we are running the LOAD DATA query on it's own